# При попытке получения элемента на странице выводит null

Tags: javascript

Создал локальную переменную и вывожу полученную хтмл сущность, но возвращает `null`. В чем подвох? Делал тоже самое вне самовызова, то же самое.

```
(function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('js_elem'); // инпут на странице с таким айди
    console.log(elem);
})();
```

Comment: Кстати, самовызова в вопросе не хватает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Самовызова нет, а результат (`null`) - есть. Магия, чо!

Comment: @Other, недокопипастил...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас javascript код выполняется до построения элемента с id: ***js_elem***.
Два пути решения:

1. Подключать js-файл в конце (внизу) html-шаблона.
2. Ждать пока документ полностью загрузится

   ***a***)

   ```
   (function(){
       document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);

       function ready(){
           var elem = document.getElementById('js_elem'); 
           console.log(elem);
       };
   )();
   ```

   ***b***) Используя JQuery:

   ```
   (function(){
       $(document).ready(ready);

       function ready() {
           var elem = $('#js_elem');
           console.log(elem);
       }
   })();
   ```

Comment: Просто интересно - зачем использовать функцию `jQuery` для ожидания загрузки, но не использовать `$` для поиска элемента?

Comment: @Other Вы правы, добавьте правильный пример к своему ответу.

Comment: Я не делал у себя примера, Ваш, в общем-то, правильный, просто странный. Поправьте у себя, если хотите.

Comment: Самовызывающаяся функция в этом варианте не слишком полезна.

Comment: Секрет - `jQuery` **тоже** ждёт загрузки документа! Т. е. путей таки 2.

Comment: недокопипастил с редактора скобки - факт, но всё таки почему консоль   выводит налл перед построением дом , не есть понятно

Comment: @dirk, как - непонятно? Поиск элемента происходит по древу `DOM`. До построения оно пустое, т. е. поиск ничего не вернёт.

Comment: @dirk getElementById так реализован, что если элемент не найден, то метод возвращает ***null***. Причина почему он не найден, в том, что дом не построен. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp

Comment: @dirk Returns null if no elements with the specified ID exists.  - возвращает null если не существует элемент с указанным ID.

Comment: @Other, нет, оно не пустое.

Comment: @dirk, до загрузки документа из скрипта можно обращаться только к элементам, которые находятся раньше него в разметке (хм.. не проверял, что там с document.write). К тому, что после - нельзя. Даже `document.body` будет null, если скрипт в head.

Comment: @Qwertiy, как же не пустое? `null` вроде означает именно отсутствие. Да, заполняется по мере парсинга, но в начале-то пустое. Хотя зачем тогда секцию `head` создали, если гуру говорят ставить скрипты вниз...

Comment: @Other в доме как минимум будет тег <script ...>, где мы подключаем наш js-код. Поэтому дерево не будет пустое.

Comment: @Max, рассматривается как бы тело, а если скрипт в `head`, то `body` пустое.

Comment: @Other, вам ответили что дерево не пустое. Потому, что ваш комментарий выше был о дереве и ответили на него...

Comment: @Max, ОК, я не прав. Проще так закончить :)

Comment: На всякий случай, [здесь вы можете проверить](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mksq9GY56yDj2HjNSRzi?p=preview), что до тега <script> из дом можно брать элементы, а после нельзя, т.к. их там еще нету. То о чем писал выше Qwertiy.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу всей страницы, но наверняка Вы ищете элемент **до** построения `DOM`.
До него ничего не найдётся. Ждите события `DOMContentLoaded` у `document` и найдёте всё.

В конец документа добавлять тоже можно, но могут быть странные глюки.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция не вызывает сама себя. Для этого необходимо добавить скобки:

```
<div id="js_elem"></div>

<script>
    (function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('js_elem');
        console.log(elem);
    })();   // <--- вот тут
</script>
```

Comment: Если бы это было причиной, о выводе null речь бы не шла. Вероятно, это просто ошибка в вопросе. К тому же: _"Делал тоже самое вне самовывозова - то же самое"_